# How can I single out certain elements in a list and get an output with user input?

Tags: python, list, input, user-input

So I'm trying to a code using python where the user inputs a certain input and in return it gives a list with just the words with a (#) in front of it.

```
def labeled():
message_input = input("Enter a message or type q to end:").split()
result = list(message_input)
lstA =[]
for i in result:
    if '#' in i :
        lstA.append(i[1:])
        continue
print(lstA)
else:
    import sys
    sys.exit()
    break
```

So far I am able to get the message the user typed and give a list as an output but I want for the user to input a message (ex: "Nice day today #running #marathon") and for python to return [running,marathon]. With this in mind too how would I take out the punctuation at the end of a word if it has it too (ex: #marathon.) output should be [marathon].

I also am trying to get the program to quit if user inputs a q specifically but until the user presses q the system should keep asking the user to input messages and once they quit it returns a list of what the user inputted.

Comment: Hint: strings have a `startswith()` method. Note that you are also selecting strings which have a `#` somewhere inside of them, which isn't the same as you described.

Answer (score 1):

You can use translate to find a specific character in following way:

```
def test():
    while(True):
        result = input("Enter a message or type q to end:")
        lstA =[]
        if result =='q':
            break
        else:
            for i in result.split():
                if i.startswith('#'):
                    lstA.append(i.translate({ord('#'): None}))
            print(lstA)

## calling test function 
test()
```

I hope, it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes so far this seems to have worked yet when I type my message like "nice day today #running #marathon" the output seems to put every word in a list when I am just trying to get the specific words in hashtags in the list. If I put "nice day today #running #marathon" they output should be [running, marathon]

Comment: Perfect!!!  Thank you!! Is there a way when I quit that python can output all the messages I put and formulate it all in the end?

Comment: @Jake, I'm happy, it helped!! Accept and up-vote my proposed solution. 

you can concatenate your messages that you want to show at the end, and if you want  cleaned text, then you can make a global list out of the function and append all what you need inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Can use a regex to search for any alphanumeric string prefixed by a `#` for example

```
import re
def labeled(s):
    return re.findall(r'#([\w\d]+)', s)

>>> labeled("Nice day today #running #marathon")
['running', 'marathon']
```

Similarly you could `str.split` the string on whitespace and keep all the substrings that `str.startwith` a `'#'` character

```
def labeled(s):
    return [i[1:] for i in s.split() if i.startswith('#')]

>>> labeled("Nice day today #running #marathon")
['running', 'marathon']
```